# How to close a serial port in Rust using serialport crate?

Tags: rust, serial-port

How do I close a serial port that I've opened? I can't see any hint about how to do this in the [docs for serialport](https://docs.rs/serialport/3.1.0/serialport/).

Comment: Can those voting to close and downvoting my question elaborate why a legitimate question, which now has a good answer describing the Rust-specific implementation is not appropriate for SO? As a result of asking, we've learned there is no close method and you need to get the port out of scope to close it.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any good answers; nothing is upvoted or accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The trait [`Serialport`](https://docs.rs/serialport/3.1.0/serialport/trait.SerialPort.html) itself does not offer such functionality<sup>1</sup>.

However the only implementor is [`TTYPort`](https://docs.rs/serialport/3.1.0/serialport/posix/struct.TTYPort.html) and its doc states:

> The port will be closed when the value is dropped.

If you look at the [`drop` implementation](https://docs.rs/serialport/3.1.0/src/serialport/posix/tty.rs.html#341), you can verify this behavior.

So, you can either use [`std::mem::drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.drop.html) directly or when the value goes out of scope the `Drop` implementation will be called (see [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-03-drop.html) about this chapter.).

---

<sup>1</sup> I would suggest opening a issue on the GitHub repository and request the functionality.

Comment: I tried using `std::mem::drop(port); break;` in the loop I'm trying to exit (that uses it), but I get "value used here after move".

Comment: When you drop the value, you will give up ownership, you can't use it afterwards (just what the error says).

Comment: I'm not using it afterwards and I don't want to use it afterwards. Is there a way to do this in an "unsafe" way and exit the loop? I'm time-constrained and I need to force the ref to be closed.